# Trying to call x86 .Net 3.5 SDK in more recent .Net versions

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

This may be a long shot...  I need to create a simple-ish web app that needs to call an OEM supplied SDK that is 10-15, or more, years old (no updates are possible).  The SDK is 32bit and is pegged to .Net Framework 3.5.  There is still an active NDA for using the SDK so there is not much that I can share.

I have access to Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019.  In each version I can go through the process of creating a C# web app and I can select .Net 3.5 as the target framework but the only available template is a "Blank" one.  Are there MVC based templates for 3.5?  I have googled and have not found any.

That is my first problem.  I decided to just move on and try newer .Net versions that might have a more complete template set.  I have tried 4.8 most recently.

Using .Net 4.8 and specifying an "x86" platform I can create a simple app.  I can call the SDK lib and get values from the simple library "get" methods like "getHeight", "getWidth", etc.  The SDK is for an old computer controlled device that still works like a charm.  It has a camera and one of the available functions is `GetCameraImage`.

The SDK comes with documentation and some sample C# "SLN"s.  One of those has the following sample code:

```
var idata = new byte[numOfBytes];
unsafe {
    fixed (byte* fixedPtr = idata) {
        channel.GetCameraImage((int) numOfBytes, out idata[0]);
    }
}
```

In my code the above just crashes with an "Access Violation".  No exceptions are thrown in the debugger.  It just dies.

The docs that come with the SDK suggest that the following is valid:

```
var idata = new byte[numOfBytes];
channel.GetCameraImage((int) numOfBytes, out idata[0]);
```

but I get the same Access Violation.

Any ideas about the Access Violation?

**EDIT**

@Serg: Addressing a couple of comments: `var idata = new byte[numOfBytes*3]` did not work but was a great idea.

@DekuDesu: I am not sure how to exactly verify that the memory is allocated so I did the following:

```
var idata = new byte[numOfBytes];
for (var i=0;i<numOfBytes;i++) {
    idata[1] += 0;
}
channel.GetCameraImage((int) numOfBytes, out idata[0]);
```

I also tried this with @Serg's offset idea and the violation is definately triggered by the `GetCameraImage` call.

Comment: Have you tried to manually verify the memory that you're sending to the `GetCameraImage(int,out byte)` method is properly allocated? such as `var pntr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(numOfBytes)`

Comment: You can also try to allocate `3*numOfBytes` and pass `idata[numOfBytes]` instead of `idata[0]`. This will prevent crash if the SDK code have a bug with buffer overrun or underrun, because you will have additional allocated bytes before and after a buffer you pass to SDK.

Comment: Thank you both. I added additional info based on your sugestions.

Comment: Can you check the SDK with simple console app targeting net3.5? Does the problem persist? If yes, can you also try to check on old OS (WinXP/Server2003 I think)+net3.5 console app (may be SDK uses some API in wrong way and in the newer OS version this way leads to crash)? The goal is following: if we will able to find working configuration, then we can crate the separate process, running in such a configuration and then passing data between this process and web app via the any transport you want (e.g. COM, sockets, pipes, message broker and so on).

Comment: @Serg: Thank you for your suggestion.  I will think about that.  There are some sample console and WinForms programs that come with the SDK and they all seem to work.